# Yii - Retrieve top 10 through CDbCriteria

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I've looked everywhere, but I can't seem to find an explanation or answer for this question.

Let's say I have a database of about 200+ users. There are two fields in the user tables that need to both be highest, to become the number one user. Field1 is more important than field2.

So for example: the user with **field1 = 5** and **field2 = 10** is higher than the user with **field1 = 5** and **field2 = 9** but lower than the user with **field1 = 6** and **field2 = 2**.

I would love to be able to generate a top 10 of all users. Also it would be great if I could select the bottom 10 or users ranking 20 to 30.

I make use if the Yii framework, so it is probably going to look something like:

```
 $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
 $users = Users::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Thanks a lot for your time and effort :)

Comment: Sorry. I downvoted by mistake. And then my internet went down and by the time it came back my vote was locked.

Comment: @topher Don't worry bro :) +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CDbCriteria::limit` and `CDbCriteria::order` as you would in sql. So to select from say 20 to 30:

```
$criteria->order = 'field1 DESC, field2 DESC'
$criteria->limit = '20, 10';
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `CDbCritria`, specify your order like so:

`$criteria->order = "field1, field2 DESC";`

That should order by field 1 first then field 2